# Writing the regex equal to string matching in java

Tags: java, regex

I wish to have a regex method that find's the exact string pattern that java accepts.

I have regex now :

```
STRINGS = \"[a-zA-Z0-9" "]*\"
```

Which does matches the strings like :

```
"this is a string"

"thisisstring"
```

But it doesn't support escape characters, so strings like :

```
"this is a sting \"\""
```

fails. Also note that this string is :

```
"this is a sting \"\"
```

Is not valid. Are there any ways such that I catch these conditions in regex?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want the text that is only between `"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a `\\\\` in your regex string (between the square brackets). The `\\` is to escape the \ in a Java string, and you need 2 `\\`'s because you need to escape the backslash in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what your strings are because they're pseudo code. But this should match all apha-numerics and the double quote:

```
String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9\" ]*";
Pattern.matches(pattern, "\"this is a sting \"");
```

And this should match all alpha-numerics, the double quote, or the combination of `\"`

```
String pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9\" ]|\\\\\")*";
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(pattern, "\"this is a sting \\\""));
```

This is because you have to escape the `\` once for the string, and once for the regex parser (so it ends up being 4 `\` in a row to match a `\` in a string).